# Is there a way to programmatically resolve a webview view without showing it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wish to trigger WebviewViewProvider.resolveWebviewView() without showing the view / the user opening the view.  I understand that you can use vscode.commands.executeCommand("myView.focus"), which would then open the view and trigger the above function.  I also tried executing the command "workbench.view.extension.myview", but that seemed to have the same action.  Instead, I want to activate the view such that the provider takes ownership of it (using resolveWebviewView), but the view remains hidden and I can still send messages to it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You got to create a different message handler.

We have a [`silentMessage` handler](https://github.com/watermelontools/wm-extension/blob/e380775ff62a2266d4ee05f16bfffb141de926b1/src/watermelonSidebar.ts#L124).